# Python: convert pdf to csv/json

Tags: python, nlp

I am new Python with converting files. I am trying to convert pdf to csv in this code and I am referring this git repo: https://github.com/bhishan/PDFMiningUsingLessAndSubprocess

I am getting error like "failed for file A Test Suite for Evaluation of English-to-Korean.pdf". Everything is working fine except 'subprocess.Popen'. What am I doing wrong here?

PDF file link (unable to add attachment on the git): http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.503.4016&rep=rep1&type=pdf

```
import subprocess
import glob
import time
import csv

csvwriter = csv.writer(file('translation.csv', 'wb'))
csvwriter.writerow(['title','contributornames','institutions','abstract'])

def parse_pdf_buffer(buffer_file):
    with open(buffer_file, 'rb') as f:
        all_content = f.readlines()
        for each_line in all_content[0:29]:
            title_part = each_line[0]
            contributornames = each_line[1]
            institutions = each_line[1:3]
            abstract = each_line[7:27]
            title_part = " ".join(desc_part.split())
            contributornames_part = " ".join(withdraw_part.split())
            institutions_part = " ".join(desc_part.split())
            abstract_part = " ".join(desc_part.split())
            csvwriter.writerow(['title','contributornames','institutions','abstract'])

def read_pdf_file(file_name):
   print file_name
   try:
       fileptr = open('koreanenglish_extracted.txt', 'wb') #parsed it from different code
       command_out = subprocess.Popen(['less', file_name], stdout=fileptr, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) #ERROR occurs here
       time.sleep(2)
       parse_pdf_buffer('koreanenglish_extracted.txt') #parsed it from different code 
   except:
       print "failed for file", file_name

def main():
   for file_name in glob.glob("*.pdf"): #capture all the pdf
       read_pdf_file(file_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

FortunatoScienceParsed.txt contents: copy paste in txt. Sorry I could not upload the files as the attachment. I"ll the send entire koreanenglish_extracted.txt in chat if needed. Help is greatly appreciated!!!

```
A Test Suite for Evaluation of English-to-Korean Machine Translation Systems
Sungryong Koh, Jinee Maeng, Ji-Young Lee, Young-Sook Chae, Key-Sun ChoiKorea Terminology Research Center for Language and Knowledge Engineering (KORTERM)
Korea Advanced Institute of Science and Technology (KAIST) 
Kusong-dong Yusong-gu Taejon 305-701 Korea
{koh,aphroditejin,jinny206}@world.kaist.ac.kr
, pinochae@chollian.net
, kschoi@cs.kaist.ac.kr
Abstract
This paper describes KORTERM™s test suite and their practicability.
 The test-sets have been being constructed on the basis of f
ine-
grained classification of linguistic phenomena 
to evaluate the technical st
atus of English-to-Korean 
MT systems systematically.
 They
consist of about 5000 test-sets and are growi
ng.
```

Comment: does the pdf contain data? if so is it in CSV or JSON format? if not why are you trying to convert a pdf to csv/json?

Comment: @depperm Yes pdf contains data. I am unable to upload the pdf doc here, but I have given the link where you can download/save it. Secondly, that what I am trying to do, convert pdf to either csv or json. The code above is for csv.

Comment: the link does not work

Comment: git: https://github.com/bhishan/PDFMiningUsingLessAndSubprocess

Comment: pdf: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.503.4016&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: How about now? @depperm

Comment: edit your answer, there is very little in that pdf that is csv, is this for just this file or multiple?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169891/discussion-between-sharp-and-depperm).

Comment: Right now I am just testing it out for 1 file only.